# Gas issue on sendRawTransaction on the rinkeby network

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, gas, rinkeby, sendrawtransaction

I'm facing a gas issue on rinkeby network on `sendRawTransaction`.

Tested with various gas value to experiment and getting either
`insufficient funds for gas * price + value`
or
`exceeds block gas limit`.

`Some more info:
Gas Estimate: 32872
Balance: 1100000 Gwei
gas: 87200`

Any suggestions or anybody faced similar issue?

My code here: https://gist.github.com/anistark/2daf9295a4d5a03cb405ff5a47924b32

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your code, you are checking the balance of an address and creating a new private key to sign the raw transaction.

```
// Original balance

let existingBalance = web3.fromWei(web3.eth.getBalance(accountAddress), balanceUnit).toString();
console.log('existingBalance:', existingBalance, balanceUnit);


// New account

let seedPhrase = lightwallet.keystore.generateRandomSeed();

lightwallet.keystore.createVault({
    password: accountKey,
    seedPhrase: seedPhrase,
    hdPathString: "m/0'/0'/0'"
}, function (err, ks) {
    ks.keyFromPassword(accountKey, function (err, pwDerivedKey) {
        ...

        // Sign with new private key

        var tx = new Tx(rawTx);
        var privateKey = new Buffer(pwDerivedKey, 'hex')
        tx.sign(privateKey);
```

The new private key is unrelated to the original address. And it will have zero balance unless funded explicitely.

Comment: Oh damn! Yes you are right. Could you also mention how to explicitly specify the private key from the keystore?

Comment: You do not want the private key from lightwallet, but from your `accountAddress`.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the info you mentioned:

```
Transaction gas limit : 87 200 gas units
Account balance: 1 100 000 wei
```

The Rinkeby network has the following properties

```
Gas Price: 1 000 000 wei (1 gwei)
Block gas limit: 7 129 048 gas units
```

It means for this particular transaction, it will cost in transaction fees:
`gas * gasPrice = 87 200 * 1 000 000 = 87 200 000 000 wei`

However you account only has `1 100 000 wei`, That why you get `insufficient funds for gas * price + value`.

For the other exception `exceeds block gas limit`, I think you put a gas linit higher than the block gas limit of the RunkeBy network.

Comment: It's 1100000 Gwei. My appologies for not mentioning before.

Updated now.

Comment: What is the gasPrice (1gwei or more) ? the gasEstimate is not expressed in gwei but in gas units. Can you send me your account address

Comment: Hi Greg,
It's 1 Gwei. I tested the same on remix browser as well.

Here's my account address: `0x1a9ef715446cf878e04fff7347202cbc4c7ed5e8`